# Vector of function calls v(f(0), f(1), ..., f(2))

Tags: r

```
f <- function(x) {
    # Does something
    return # an integer
}
```

How do I create a vector of function calls that is equivalent to:

`v(f(0), f(1),  ..., f(n))`

Comment: Do you need `sapply(0:n, f)` or `Vectorize(f)(0:n)`

Comment: @akrun Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the arguments if the function is not vectorized  in `sapply` (as `sapply` returns a `vector` if the output element is a single value

```
sapply(0:n, f)
```

Or we `Vectorize` the function and pass the multiple values

```
Vectorize(f)(0:n)
```